# How to use an interface between classes and derived classes?

Tags: c#, class, interface

I am currently trying to make a chess game and have tried to implement an interface however I cannot access the interface.

```
public interface IChessPiece
{
     bool CheckMove(int row, int col);
}

public class ChessPiece { ... }

public class Pawn : ChessPiece, IChessPiece
{
     public bool CheckMove(int row, int col) { ... }
}

public class ChessPieces {  public List<ChessPieces> chessPieces; ... }
```

I cannot seem to access the **CheckMove()** method.

```
board.chessPieces.Find(x => <condition>).CheckMove(row, col);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement `ChessPiece` as *abstract class*:

```
public interface IChessPiece {
  bool CheckMove(int row, int col);
}

// Note "abstract"
public abstract class ChessPiece: IChessPiece {
  ... 

  // Note "abstract"
  public abstract bool CheckMove(int row, int col);
}

// Pawn implements IChessPiece since it's derived form ChessPiece
public class Pawn: ChessPiece {
  // Actual implementation
  public override bool CheckMove(int row, int col) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class also requires to implement the `IChessPiece` interface and most likely make it `abstract`, since it should not be instanciated directly. Then you should change the `List` on the board to have `IChessPiece` type:

```
public class ChessPiece : IChessPiece { ... }

public class Pawn : ChessPiece, IChessPiece
{
     public bool CheckMove(int row, int col) { ... }
}

public class ChessPieces {  public List<IChessPieces> chessPieces; ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

implement `IChessPiece` in `ChessPiece` class.

```
public class ChessPiece : IChessPiece { ... }
```

> I cannot seem to access the CheckMove() method.

Because you know ChessPieces implement CheckMove, but compiler does not.

If you donot want to implement `IChessPiece` interface into `ChessPiece` class, then you need to typecast like

```
  ((IChessPiece)(board.chessPieces.Find(x => <condition>))).CheckMove(row, col);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1. You may want to implement the interface in the ChessPiece class - it makes more sense to me because of the interface name too. If you need to implement the method in derived classes, then make it an abstract method.
2. Get a list of all ChessPieces implementing the interface: `ChessPieces.OfType<IChessPiece>`

Answer (score 1):

The `ChessPiece` does not have the `CheckMove` method. You could do this:

```
public abstract class ChessPiece : IChessPiece
{
    public abstract bool CheckMove(int row, int col);
}
```

This makes sure that anyone deriving from the ChessPiece base class, must also implement the CheckMove method. Any class deriving from ChessPiece, will also implement IChessPiece.

```
public class Pawn : ChessPiece // implicitly also implements IChessPiece
{
    public override bool CheckMove(int row, int col) 
    {
    }
}
```

However, the idea of an interface is that when working with them, the implementation should not matter. Therefore, your `List<ChessPiece>` should really be a `List<IChessPiece>` - that would actually be enough, as any items added to that list **must** implement IChessPiece, but the base class is irrelevant.